# Insertion of arrays in to respective excel columns

Tags: php, arrays, rows, multiple-columns, fgetcsv

m having 3 arrays say:

```
$first_array = array('val11','val21','val31');
$Second_array = array('val12','val22','val32');
$third_array = array('val13','val23','val33');
```

Is it possible to store this array values using `fgetcsv()` function of php in to each column, i mean,
 first_array should be store in first column,
 second array in second columnn and third to third..
so the data should be like

```
val11 val12 val31
val21 val22 val32
val31 val32 val33
```

is there anyway please let me know . 
thanks

Comment: Why don't you use [PHP Excel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)? It's free.

Comment: @JaredFarrish It's also a hateful API and very poorly documented. Not your fault, just saying. It's a pet hate of mine. To the extent that a lot of the time if I need to manipulate proper Excel files (not just CSV) I do it on Windows with COM.

Comment: @DaveRandom - I've never had that "luxuery" (?). Debian for going on ten years now. The only time I do export to "Excel" it's HTML tables. I just tell people to ignore the warning. And I didn't even notice the CSV part. Duh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to flip the arrays from columns to rows.

Assuming that all the arrays have the same number of elements, this should do the job:

```
$rows = array();

// Converts the arrays of columns into arrays of rows
$length = count($first_array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  $rows[$i] = array($first_array[$i], $second_array[$i], $third_array[$i]);
}

// Writes the rows to the file
$fp = fopen('outfile.csv', 'w');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
<?php
    $list = array (
        array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
        array('123', '456', '789'),
        array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
    );
    $fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    fclose($fp);
 ?>
```